# How i can current date Outputfilename Data Extract Arcgis Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, arcgis

```
outputFileName = (configXML.outputfilename[0] || "Dataextracted") + ".zip";
outputFileName = outputFileName.replace(/(\\|\/|:|\?|"|<|>|\|)/g, "");
```

"Dataextracted" change current date time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "Dataextracted" with

```
new Date()
```

To format it:

```
var df:spark.formatters.DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter();
df.dateTimePattern = "yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss";
trace(df.format(new Date())); //output 2016-Oct-13-095823
```

Comment: use the DateFormatter class

Comment: can u help me for reference?